# Can't insert value to database in android

Tags: android, database, insert, sqliteopenhelper

I created a database with follow code :

```
public class DataEncryptHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database
    // version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBSample.db";
    Context mContext;

    public DataEncryptHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Model.SQL_CREATE_STORY);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy
        // is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(Model.SQL_DELETE_STORY);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
    public void insertStory(String title, String content) {
        DataEncryptHelper mDbHelper = new DataEncryptHelper(mContext);
        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Model.COL_TITLE_STORY, title);
        values.put(Model.COL_CONTENT_STORY, content);

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        db.insert(Model.TABLE_STORY, null, values);
    }
}
```

And this is class Model :

```
public class Model {

    public static final String TEXT_TYPE    = "TEXT";
    public static final String INTEGER_TYPE = "INTEGER";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE     = "KEY";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP   = ",";

    // TABLE STORY
    public static final String TABLE_STORY       = "Story";
    public static final String COL_TITLE_STORY   = "title_story";
    public static final String COL_CONTENT_STORY = "content_story";
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_STORY  = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STORY
            + " (" + COL_TITLE_STORY + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + COL_CONTENT_STORY + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
    public static final String SQL_DELETE_STORY  = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + TABLE_STORY;

}
```

And in MainActivity :

```
DataEncryptHelper dbEncrypt = new DataEncryptHelper(this);
dbEncrypt.insertStory("title1", "content1");
```

But when run project,it display error :

> (1) table Story has no column named title_story
>          Error inserting title_story=title1 content_story=content1
>          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Story has no column 
>   named title_story (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Story(title_story,content_story) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: You should look up what columns are. Then define columns for your table and then try inserting data into the said columns.

Comment: Did you add the `title_story` after create the db first time. If yes you must increment the `DATABASE_VERSION` by 1

Comment: @ramaral: i increased version from 1 to 2. But it also display errors. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space after field name

```
// TABLE STORY
public static final String TABLE_STORY = "Story ";
public static final String COL_TITLE_STORY = "title_story ";
public static final String COL_CONTENT_STORY = "content_story ";
public static final String SQL_CREATE_STORY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STORY
        + " (" + COL_TITLE_STORY + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
        + COL_CONTENT_STORY + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
public static final String SQL_DELETE_STORY = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
        + TABLE_STORY;
```